Ruby on Rails testing controller for nested form creation
I have a model entities with a HMT relationship in the model user_entity_roles. I create new entities with a nested form. In the controller, this is a 2 step process via the new and create methods. I can't figure out how to write a test for creating a new entity.
Models:
class Entity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices, dependent: :restrict_with_error
  has_many :user_entity_roles, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_entity_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_entity_roles, dependent: :restrict_with_error
  belongs_to :invoice_number_format
  has_many :debitors, dependent: :restrict_with_error
  validates_associated :user_entity_roles

  validates :company, presence: true
  validates :street, presence: true
  validates :house_number, presence: true
  validates :zip, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
end

class UserEntityRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :entity, touch: true
  belongs_to :user
  validates :entity_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end

Entities Controller:
def new
  @entity = Entity.new
  @entity.user_entity_roles.build
  @entity.user_entity_roles.first.user_id = Current.user.id
end

def create
  @entity = Entity.new(entity_params)
  if @entity.save
    redirect_to @entity
  else
    render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

Entities Test Controller:
test 'should create entity with valid params' do
  sign_in_as @user
  assert_difference -> { Entity.count }, 1 do
    post entities_url, params: {
      entity: {
        company: 'MyString',
        street: 'MyString',
        house_number: 'MyString',
        zip: 'MyString',
        city: 'MyString',
        tax_number: 'MyString',
        vat_id: 'MyString',
        hrb: 'MyString',
        invoice_number_format_id: 2,
        user_entity_roles_attributes: {
          id: 0, # This is wrong
          user_id: @user.id,
          is_manager: 1,
          is_editor: 1
        }
      }
    }
  end
end

This doesn't work, because the entity_id in the nested user_entity_role must be the id of the newly created entity.
Edit: Per the first answer, this is also in the controller. Maybe the error is there?
  def entity_params
    params.require(:entity).permit(:id, :company, :street, :house_number, :zip, :city, :tax_number, :vat_id, :hrb,:managing_director, :iban, :bank, :invoice_number_format_id, user_entity_roles_attributes: %i[id is_manager is_editor user_id])
  end


it's a has_many association, so user_entity_roles_attributes needs to be an array of hashes [{...}]. or a sort of indexed hash that is submitted by the form: {"0" => {...}} (see your logs). the id: 0 is not needed when creating a new record.

You should NEVER be accepting the current user id as a parameter. You're making it trivial for a malicous user to spoof authentication and either create resources as other users or to get other users to create resources for them. Get it from the session instead.

Thank you Alex, I managed to make the two parameter identical now by logging to console and test.log and carefully comparing. However, I get 422 unprocessable entity in testing while it works in server. Maybe there is something different in my fixtures, I need to check all of that now.

Thank you max, I was able to remove all user-id passing through forms and insert it from the session before saving.

What I don't get here is why the user_entity_role is being created from user input at all and not just being created in the controller. Should the user really be able to decide which role they get?

@max, the idea was that the owner of the entity can assign roles to other users, including all responsibility (is_manager). However, here, where the entity is created, there is only the role of the owner to consider. When I work on the roles a bit more I will need to put back some form of user id in the parameters but this will be done in a different controller.

You still need to do a lot of thinking about the security implications of that feature and come up with a better implementation. I would use a separate route/controller instead of trying to do this with nested attributes.

What I don't get here is why the user_entity_role is being created from user input at all and not just being created in the controller.
Surely it's not up to the user to decide the authorization logic for newly created items in your application?
def new
  @entity = Entity.new
end

def create
  @entity = Entity.new(entity_params)
  @entity.user_entity_roles.new(
    user: Current.user,
    is_manager: true,
    is_editor: true
  )
  if @entity.save
    redirect_to @entity
  else
    render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

# ...

def entity_params
    params.require(:entity) # line breaks are free dude
          .permit(
             :company, :street, :house_number, # do not include id
             :zip, :city, :tax_number, 
             :vat_id, :hrb,:managing_director, 
             :iban, :bank, :invoice_number_format_id
           )
end

def valid_params
 {
   entity: {
     company: 'MyString',
     street: 'MyString',
     house_number: 'MyString',
     zip: 'MyString',
     city: 'MyString',
     tax_number: 'MyString',
     vat_id: 'MyString',
     hrb: 'MyString',
     invoice_number_format_id: 2
   }
 }
end

test 'should create entity with valid params' do
  sign_in_as @user
  assert_difference -> { Entity.count }, 1 do
    post entities_url, params: valid_params
  end
end

test 'should add role to user' do
  assert_difference -> { @user.user_entity_roles.count }, 1 do
    post entities_url, params: valid_params
  end  
end

You should carefully consider what attributes in your model you're actually exposing though your API.
Additionally having boolean attributes prefaced with is_ is in itself an anti-pattern. There are much better ways to this beyond having an ever growing number of boolean columns in the table like for example having a roles table containing a definition and a user_roles table that joins roles and users.

You don't need to pass an id in for the associated entity role. It will get one automatically after it gets created. Then you can get it for test purposes with UserEntityRole.last

I think the id is the entity's id, not the user_entity_role's id. But this got me thinking: when I try this without the id I get an error because of the missing id. I also have this method in the controller:
def entity_params
params.require(:entity).permit(:id, :company, :street, :house_number, :zip, :city, :tax_number, :vat_id, :hrb, :managing_director, :iban, :bank, :invoice_number_format_id,user_entity_roles_attributes: %i[id is_manager is_editor user_id])
end

@Ricky883249 you shouldn't need to require the object's own id . That gets assigned to it from a sequence from the db on first save. The id for the other id should be called user_id but you also don't need that if it's a nested object, it will get that assigned to it from the association

thank you, you were right. I was able to remove all ids and can still make it work in server. In Testing it still doesn't work but this could be a different problem now.

@Ricky883249 let us know what other problem you're experiencing. If you want to accept this answer that'd be great too!

I found the problem and it is a bit embarrassing. It was invoice_number_format.id = 2. When working with fixtures, the id is some random number. I changed this to invoice_number_format_id: @invoice_number_format.id and now the test goes through! Thank you, I can now focus on some of the suggested improvements.
